# ansible equivalent of docker run "-c"

Tags: postgresql, docker, ansible

to run a docker postgres container with custom config you would use a command like this:

"docker container run -d postgres -c max_connections=6 -c log_lock_waits=on"

i have the task as:

```
name: Start postgis
  become: true
  docker_container:
    name: postgis
    image: "{{ ecr_url }}"    
    network_mode: bridge
    exposed_ports:
      5432
    published_ports:
      5432:5432
    state: started
    volumes:
    - /mnt/datadir/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

which will indeed run the container, but then my question is:

what is the equivalent in asible of the "-c" flag in the docker run command??

---

thanks larsks for the answer, you can send multiple commands one below the other

```
published_ports:
      5432:5432
    state: started
    command:
      -c shared_buffers = 24000MB
      -c work_mem=16MB
      -c maintenance_work_mem = 128MB
      -c etcetera
```

Comment: Thanks, this method works, just a small tweak, space around '=' in the commands failed for me.  Everything else worked.

Comment: i cant really remember if it worked for me with the spaces around the '=', but if anybody else can confirm on whenever or not they are permited i will make the edit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that the syntax for the `docker run` is:

```
docker run [...docker options...] image [...command and args...]
```

With that in mind, look at your command line:

```
docker container run -d postgres -c max_connections=6 -c log_lock_waits=on
```

Those `-c` arguments come *after* the image name, so they are **not** flags to `docker run`.  They are instead part of the command being passed into the container and in this case they end up being arguments to the `postgres` command.

So in Ansible, you would just have:

```
docker_container:
  name: postgis
  image: "{{ ecr_url }}"    
  command: "-c max_connections=6 -c log_lock_waits=on"
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, one quick question can i use multiple commands? to not have a long line but some lines shorter

Comment: In general, sure, you can chain together multiple commands like `command:  "command1; command2; command3", but in this specific case that probably won't work since the "command" value is getting passed to the `postgres` cli rather than a shell.

Comment: thanks for commenting, you can pass multiple commands one below the other with no problem